# jQuery UI Datepicker incorrect display

Tags: jquery-ui

Simply trying to display two months in a single row.
But keep getting the following (also note duplication of month)
Any ideas?
[image]

```
$(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker(
            {
                numberOfMonths: [1,2] ,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                showButtonPanel: false
            });
        });
```

Have also tried
numberOfMonths: [2,1] produces same result

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      showButtonPanel: true
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      //selectOtherMonths: true,
      //showOtherMonths: true,
      showButtonPanel: false

});
```

Reference [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#multiple-calendars)